# Computational time complexity of std::map::merge

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, std, c++17, stdmap

C++17 introduces an `std::map::merge` function for merging an `std::map` into an another.

Since `std::map` is an ordered associative container, more explicitly a *self-balancing binary search tree* (most frequently implemented as a Red-Black Tree or AVL Tree), I would expect that `std::map::merge` takes advantage of the fact that the elements of both `std::map`s are already sorted, so there is no need to search the place of insertion for every single element, i.e. the time complexity should be amortized linear `O(N)`.

Interestingly,  [cppreference says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/merge) that the computational time complexity of `std::map::merge` is logarithmic `O(N*log(N))`:

> **Complexity** N*log(size()+N)), where N is source.size()

Is that correct?

In this case `std::map::merge` seems to be equivalent to `std::map::insert(iterator begin, iterator end)`, making `std::map::merge` completely superfluous.

What is the actual truth about the time complexity of `std::map::merge`?

Comment: The method was introduced as a wrapper for mass-splicing, not to take advantage of sorted nature of two containers. It makes no assumptions about comparators being in-sync with each other.

Comment: @AnT Yeah, but it could be easily solved by a promise that the comparators are in sync using tag dispatching for example.

Comment: maybe there is a specialisation for the case both maps use the same comparater, but that wont change the fact that in general the complexity is worse

Comment: @user463035818 Comparators are generally considered stateful objects. Two comparators of the same type don't have to produce the same ordering.

Comment: @AnT yes didnt consider this. Can imagine it is difficult for stateful comparators to ensure a strict weak ordering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would expect that std::map::merge takes advantage of the fact that
>   the elements of both std::maps are already sorted, so there is no need
>   to search the place of insertion for every single element [...]

You are missing the fact that the map to be merged may be of a different type, ie it might use a different sorting:

```
template <class C2>
void merge(std::map<Key, T, C2, Allocator>& source); 
                            ^--- this is not necessarily the same as for the map you 
                                 are merging into
```

So actually the map to be merged has to be considered not sorted to get the worst case complexity.

Comment: They could provide an overload for the case when the comparator types are the same. Anyway, that would be still possible that stateful comparators are in different state, regardless that their type is the same. Still, it could be easily solved by a promise that the comparators are in sync using tag dispatching for example, like `std::map::merge(map, comp_sync_tag)`.

Comment: @plasmacel actually not sure anymore what your question is.... Can two maps be merged in linear time? Yes. Is `std::map::merge` linear? No.

Comment: You answered the question. I'm just saying that this function smells from weak design. It lacks some very useful features, just like `std::vector` lacks a `resize` function which doesn't initialize. Sometimes the incompleteness of `std` does really surprise me.

Comment: @plasmacel i could imagine that the reasoning was that if you have two maps of same type then merging them is almost trivial and there is no urgent need for introducing a method into the standard

Comment: Yeah, using `std::map::insert(hint, value)`, where `hint` is the `end()` iterator of the other map performs in-order insertion in constant time - using this fact one can perform a merge (by inserting the items of the other map one by one) in linear time.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a possible implementation of this method:

```
for (auto const& iter : source)
{
   dest. insert( iter);
}
```

So you iterate over the source map (complexity N), and insert each element into the destination map which has complexity log(dest.size()+N).
As the other answer by user463035818 already pointed out, the order of the two maps is not necessarily the same, so you have to insert each element separately.
And finally, must tree sorting algorithms are built in a way that you traverse the tree from the root node down and do the balancing on the way down or when going back up again. It would be difficult to write an algorithm that traverses the tree in order, adds elements **and** balances the tree.